# Is it possible for order collection filter by attribute?

Tags: orders, filter

I need to filter the order collections based product attributes. Is it possible. Product attributes stored in `sales_flat_order_item ( product_options)`. But in this field stored in serialization form. How to search the orders based on the product attributes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - order collection is non_EAV (flat) collection so you filter it by field (method `addFieldToFilter`) not by attribute.

To have possibility of using fields from table `sales_flat_order_item` you should make a join to `sales_flat_order` collection (and you will join fields with values same as attributes but I am not sure if we can call the exactly attributes).

Then if you have fields with attribute values you want to filter by it is extremely easy to do it :).

Every simple element of this task you can find in internet.